# sequelize-cli db:migrate doesn't generate association table

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have a `User` model (with associated migration file created by `sequelize-cli`):

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const User = sequelize.define('User', {
        dispName: DataTypes.STRING,
        email: DataTypes.STRING,
        phoneNum1: DataTypes.STRING
    }, {});
    User.associate = function (models) { // associations added manually
        User.belongsToMany(models.Role, { through: 'UserRoles', foreignKey: 'userId' });
    };
    return User;
};
```

here's the generated migration file:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Users', {
      cognitoId: { // modified: was an auto-incrementing integer
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.STRING(100)
      },
      dispName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(100) // modified: was just plain STRING
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(100) // modified: was just plain STRING
      },
      phoneNum1: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(15) // modified: was just plain STRING
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Users');
  }
};
```

and a `Role` model (with associated migration file created by `sequelize-cli`):

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Role = sequelize.define('Role', {
        name: DataTypes.STRING
    }, {});
    Role.associate = function (models) { // associations added manually
        Role.belongsToMany(models.User, { through: 'UserRoles', foreignKey: 'roleId' });
    };
    return Role;
};
```

here's the generated migration file for `Role`:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Roles', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(100), // modified: was just plain STRING
        unique: true // Added manually
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Roles');
  }
};
```

When I run `sequelize-cli db:migrate`, the table `UserRoles` is not created. Why is that?

The [Associations](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/associations.html) page of the Sequelize manual seems to suggest that defining the associations in the model file is all that is required...

Research:

- I seem to have done what is suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57353991/) to the question [Sequelize not creating model association columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57351863/) but doesn't seem to be working for me (the answer isn't accepted either).
- Not quite what I need: [Querying association tables in Sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37570926/)
- Nor this: [Sequelize how to use association table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43997395/)

Comment: show the generated migrations

Comment: Updated with migration files @Anatoly.

Comment: don't see any UserRoles in migrations. How did you create them?

Comment: That's precisely it: I was expecting that the `UserRoles` will be magically generated by sequelize. So I finally ended up writing the `UserRoles` migration file manually.

Comment: We usually do the same. But you could write the model for UserRoles and generate migration from it